# How I can make apt-get install to my virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, apt-get

It it's possible, of course.

For example - I can download python-dbus like this:
    $ sudo apt-get download python-dbus

But what I should to do next, with this .deb package in my current virtualenv?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you really need to do it this way, you can just copy the files that get installed globally directly into your virtualenv. For example I couldn't get pycurl working since the required libraries weren't installing, but `apt-get install python-pycurl` did. So I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pycurl
cp /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pycurl* ~/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

The install said it was adding it to /usr/lib/python2.7. So I looked in that directory for a site-packages or dist-packages with pycurl, after looking at the files I copied them into my virtualenv. You'd have to also copy any executables from bin into your virtualenv's bin directory.

Also, running a `pip install -r requirements.txt` successfully found pycurl in there and just skipped over it as if I had installed it via pip.

Comment: Yep. I found the same decision - just a link (ln s) to libraries which was installed via apt-get.

Comment: This doesn't work for PyQt5 on Python 3. Returns "ImportError: No module named 'sip' when trying to import QWidgets

Comment: This did the trick! Just wanted to point out that I needed to ensure that the name of the file reflected the version of Python installed within my virtualenv. e.g. apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so for Python 3.6

Comment: But what if the the system python and venv python have different version?

Answer (score 12):

To include system site packages in your existing virtual environment open the config file:
`<PATH_TO_YOUR_VENV_FOLDER>/pyvenv.cfg`

and change `false` to `true` for `include-system-site-packages`

```
include-system-site-packages = true
```

Save and reload your virtual environment.

*(tested with virtualenv 20.2.2 on Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) to pull in python3-pyqt5 installed with apt into my virtual environment)*

If it is for a new environment @Joshua Kan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53515591/2974621) using the `--system-site-packages` flag with the `venv` command is probably what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Why would you want to do this? The whole point is to avoid doing stuff like that...

```
virtualenv whatever
cd whatever
bin/pip install dbus-python
```

You may also choose to specify `--no-site-packages` to `virtualenv` to keep it extra isolated.

Comment: Recent versions of virtualenv deprecate --no-site-packages, since it's the new default.

Comment: Thx for your answer. But I mean thouse case when we are can't use pip install - just have a repository in .deb format - what I should to do then?

Comment: @АлександрКривошеев Well, if you can get the source from the package, then use `setup.py` to install it, or find the appropriate equivalent on pypi or github etc... Otherwise - there's not a lot you can do...

Comment: Sometimes we are have no possibility to find setup.py and $ pip install dbus-python in this case makes [error 2] we are have no setup.py :[

Comment: Just to check, you are using `pip` in the bin directory of your virtualenv, not the system wide `pip`? If you don't have `setup.py`'s, then you have to arrange directories by hand - not something you want to do if you can avoid it...

Comment: No, of course it was activated virtualenv like ---(smth_v_env) $ pip install dbus-python--- and after pip was download this one I can just find in it's directory only ./config file - to compile it manually. May be I'm wrong - not environment :)

Answer (score 4):

An alternative solution is to install globally, then followed by allowing the virtualenv to be able to see it.
As an example, let's say we want to install matplotlib for Python 3:

1. `sudo apt update` # Update first
2. `sudo apt install python3-matplotlib`  # Install globally
3. `sudo pip3 install -U virtualenv`  # Install virtualenv for Python 3 using pip3
4. `virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python3 ./venv` #the system-site-packages option allows venv to see all global packages including matplotlib
5. `source ./venv/bin/activate` #activate the venv to use matplotlib within the virtualenv
6. `deactivate`  # don't exit until you're done using the virtualenv

Answer (score 3):

First install the dbus development libraries (you may need some other dev libraries, but this is all I needed)

```
sudo apt-get install libdbus-1-dev libdbus-glib-1-dev
```

Next, with your virtualenv activated, run the following. It'll fail but that's ok.

```
pip install dbus-python
```

Finally, go into your virtualenv's build directory and install it the non-pythonic way.

```
cd $VIRTUAL_ENV/build/dbus-python
chmod +x configure
./configure --prefix=$VIRTUAL_ENV
make
make install
```