# Using Apt-Get Python Packages Inside Virtual Environment

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, pandas, virtualenv

I have installed pandas with apt-get package manager via code

`sudo apt-get install python3-pandas`

Because `pip install pandas` hungs long time.

I need to use pandas inside a virtual environment. How can i use a apt-get installed Python package inside virtual environment?

Comment: This is arguably a duplicate of [make virtualenv inherit specific packages from your global site packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079607/make-virtualenv-inherit-specific-packages-from-your-global-site-packages), unless one wishes to just have *all* site packages be accessible (as `virtualenv --system-site-packages` will); I'm sure we have another prospective dupe for that simpler case.

Comment: Why would you do this? Why not just download padnas from its website and then create an environment with `conda create`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How I can make apt-get install to my virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441546/how-i-can-make-apt-get-install-to-my-virtualenv)

Answer (score 1):

I have simply copied the original pandas directory to the virtual environment directory.

```
cp -R /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas /home/pi/.virtualenvs/insta/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```