# Can't install Python 2 `gtop` module in virtual environment

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyenv

I'm trying to run the [benchmarks game repo bencher script](https://salsa.debian.org/benchmarksgame-team/benchmarksgame/-/tree/master/bencher) which was written in python 2 and requires the `gtop` module, NOT the `pygtop` module. After searching everywhere and even following their README.md I could not figure out how to get this in my python 2.7.18 virtual environment (created and maintained using `pyenv`).

I decided to have a look at my system version of python 2.7.18 as I followed the guide from this [SO reply](https://askubuntu.com/a/1253597/1058962) and the packages downloaded/installed successfully. My system version of python can import the module just fine:

```
Python 2.7.18 (default, Mar  8 2021, 13:02:45) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gtop
>>> gtop.__file__
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtop.so'
```

So apparently it comes as a `.so` which I've researched is like a DLL library for Ubuntu (correct me if I'm wrong)?

Is there a way for me to just copy this into my virtual environment of the same python version?

Comment: There seems to be a similar issue with python-dbus here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13710008/1581658 is that any help for which files to copy into your virtual env?

Comment: And you are correct, an `.so` is the Linux equivalent of a `DLL` They are both known as shared libraries. (There are some differences in how they work - but they fulfill the same task - providing compiled code that can be loaded by other running programs)

Comment: @SamBob thank you for providing a link! I believe something similar was the solution.

Basically what I've been doing is copying the `gtk-2.0` directory into my virtualenvs `site-packages` directory. What I've done is instead copy just the `gtop.so` directly into the virtualenvs `site-packages` directory and it seemed to recognise it no problem.

Extremely odd how it only recognises the package if it's standalone under `site-packages`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to @SamBob for suggesting the SO reply that led to the answer.

What I've been mistakenly doing is copying the `gtk-2.0` **directory** into my virtualenvs `site-packages` such that:

```
$HOME/.pyenv/versions/<venv>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtop.so
```

What I've done is instead copy just the `gtop.so` library into the virtualenvs `site-packages`, and it seemed to recognise it no problem, such that

```
$HOME/.pyenv/versions/<venv>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtop.so
```

Here is my output now:

```
Python 2.7.18 (default, Oct 18 2021, 23:18:58) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gtop
>>> gtop.__file__
'/home/muffin/.pyenv/versions/project-2.7.18/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtop.so'
>>>
```